# Multiple Same Apps and Deep Linking

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, deep-linking

I have implemented deep linking in my app. I added this intent filter in my manifest file, and the deep linking is working fine.

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data
                    android:host="xxxxxxxx"
                    android:scheme="xxxxxxxx" />
            </intent-filter>
```

The problem is that through deep linking, when i click on my App, it is showing similiar kinds of apps.
It is happening when Open by DEFAULT is not set
But when the open by default is set then everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way ..
Suppose when user call http://example.com that time my Mainactivity open then all required attribute define inside mainactivity.

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity"> 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name = ".MainActivity" > 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="example.com"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: But I need it in one activity eg:- in SplashActivity itself

Comment: what every activity to open on like that time view and BROWSABLE .

Comment: Can u please elaborate?